# To store or not to store ... in the database

Tags: mysql

So, I'm constructing a MYSQL database. In this database, a table called `pendingArchives` exists. Until an administrator can approve an archived file, it remains "unapproved", or "0" as it's an integer field. However, my question to you all is whether or not a record should be removed from the `pendingArchives` table once it has been approved. As of now, I am simply setting the `approved` field to have a value of "1" which means that it has been approved.

So, please let me know, which is the more agreed upon method, simply setting the approved value to 1, or moving the record to a completely new `approved` table?

Comment: Can an item become unapproved after being approved?  Would you also want to record the approver's identity and timestamp?

Comment: This is a very good point, now that I think about it - yes it can. Just answered my question didn't you ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can let it act as a history table and not delete any record, as well as rename it to `archiveStatus`

Or you can create a new table named `archiveHistory` and move it there.

For both cases, make sure that there's a date column for the approval date, and have a trigger ready to modify it whenever a `status` column (for approved and unapproved values) is modified.

[edit / additional]

In my experience, tracking activities is one of the best pleasures a DBA where I used to work at would like to have. With data warehouses, other VLDBs and users who almost always question reports, we like to show this kind of evidence that an action has been taken, then confirmed, then backed up or implemented further to the users. With secured tables in which only jobs or SSIS package runs can modify, loading of data, correcting of data, insertion of data gets logged, as well as all other changes like database backup start and end times, execution results, who ran what when and from where.. It's always good to have a way to track things. Avoid deleting unless the circumstance calls for it (erroneous insertion resulting in duplicates, for example) but still log the activities. In those cases, it's okay to admit a mistake, as long as the steps to rectify are confirmed and that there is always solid evidence to back it up. Another thing.. for the DBA team and management, you can even make a report out of properly set-up tracking tables.

Comment: I like this answer, covers every possible issue.

Comment: I hope it helps. Added some more info based on past experiences.. Properly setting up your tracking tables is key to avoiding having to move data from one table to another. Restructure your table so that it can act as a proper history/tracking table that can be used to manage jobs, recheck any requirements, etc

Comment: Well the obvious decision then seems to weight out the pros / cons for each option and choose accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I would move move the record to a new table because of organization it's ease to work with/read. Then you wouldn't have to filter out the approved from the unapproved.

Comment: I considered this, of course, but as another user cleverly pointed out, there is a chance that an item becomes unapproved after some time. This would require the record to be in the original table I assume.

Comment: @Evan Consider how big each table could grow - and consider how often each operation shall occur. Think 10 years down the line is 99% of your data going to be in 1 table - do you need it?

Comment: @AdrianCornish this is a good point, too. So if an item becomes unapproved, I would then need to move it back to the pending table?

Comment: @Evan Interesting today I had a conversation about the pros cons of soft deletes with our expert DBA today. Result was requirements drive the result and data management is outside of this. Implement as column, as a table as indexed view (and more) each has pros/cons which is applicable to your problem

Answer (score 1):

As with most MYSQL design questions, this is all about what types of operations you will need to do and the size of the data set.  Moving it to another table seems like extra overhead unless you will be doing other operations with the approved ones which would require other indices etc.

Answer (score 1):

A common practice is not to delete such records, but set their IsActive/IsValid/etc. field to 0. This is especially important if such records are referred to from other tables, or when you expect that they will be needed later in a historical analysis.

Answer (score 0):

This really depends on what your data retention/audit requirements are. There are many pros/cons/opinions to both - I suggest searching google for "soft delete vs hard delete"

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting question. Ultimately, the answer is "it depends". Here are some things to consider:

1. How often will you be selecting for approved records vs unapproved records? If you are selecting for one a lot more often than the other, that may mean separating the data is worthwhile.
2. How will the data grow? Presumably, approved records will grow over time and unapproved records will grow more of a function of users. If this is so, that means over time, the amount of approved records will begin to dwarf unapproved records. This also argues for separating the data.
3. What kind of operations are allowable for approved vs unapproved records? For example, can you only delete/update unapproved records? If so, that also argues for separating out the records, since then you could limit write locks to a specific table and even use different DB permissions to enforce this constraint.
4. Will you have the requirement of showing both unapproved and approved records in the same result set? That would argue for keeping them together.

Hope this is helpful.